# Making an SSIS export to excel package work on the server

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I use to export to excel.
I moved my package to my server and it doesnt have an MS Office installation.

My question is , how do I make my package work on the server without an MS Office installation.
Is there anything like an extension that I can use ??

Comment: Can you show error message please? It is not clear what's going on.

Comment: Are you using Excel Interop? If so then to use it you will need to install Excel on the server. *However*, this is not recommended. I would use OLEDB to write to excel, this will work on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. But I do not think it is required to export data to Excel.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Hey I am exporting data to an excel file which is also located on the server. Right now I cannot read any excel file on the server since MS office is not installed. If I install this. Will I be able to read the excel file on the server ?

Comment: Yes. You don't need Excel installed to write to an Excel file from SSIS but you always need Excel installed to... open it in Excel. Normally you don't install client tools like Excel on a server though.